# Как обратиться к элементу nested dict python?

Tags: python, dict

Есть nested dictionary вида:
{"John": {"Secret": "qweetgdsjre123", "uid": "12314125"}}
Как "достать" элемент uid, при условии того что первый элемент "John" - переменная и будет постоянно изменяться?

Comment: `[d[i]["uid"] for i in d]`

Comment: Спасибо, нашел решение)

Answer (score 0):

```
for k, v in json.loads(line).items():
  text[k[:]]['uid'] = username
```

Сам спросил, сам ответил =)